# NA in visweb function of bipartite package

Tags: r

i am fighting with a problem in the graphical visweb function of the bipartite package. It says or I assume that it can handle NA values since the code is:

```
visweb(web, type="nested",  prednames=TRUE, preynames=TRUE, labsize=1,
  plotsize=12, square="interaction", text="no", frame=NULL, textsize=1,
  textcol="red", pred.lablength=NULL, prey.lablength=NULL, clear=TRUE,
  xlabel="", ylabel="", boxes=TRUE, circles=FALSE, circle.col="black",
  circle.min=0.2, circle.max=2, outerbox.border="white", 
  outerbox.col="white", box.border="black", box.col="black", def.col="blue", 
  max.digits=4, NA.col="red")
```

and at the end ist says, that the color for visualizing NA values can be chosen. Nevertheless, as soon as I start feeding it with my matrix that contains NA values R gives back this error message:

Error in while (max(w) > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Since I want to compare this plot to other plots, I would prefer not to exclude the NA values. 
This is the code I am working with:

```
visweb(Consensus_5_18, type="none", box.border="white",
       clear=F, labsize=1, NA.col = "red")
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, since i don't have your data I used the `Safaridata` from the package and added an NA:

```
Safariland2 <- Safariland
Safariland2[2,1]<-NA
```

Then used the same code as you did and got the same error

```
visweb(Safariland2, type="none", box.border="white", clear=F, labsize=1, NA.col = "red")
```

Then checked one by one the values you changed untile I found that Clear was the problem:

```
visweb(Safariland2, type="none", box.border="white", clear=T, labsize=1, NA.col = "red")
```

[image]

Althought I prefer to use this one:

```
visweb(Safariland2, type="none", box.border="black", clear=T, labsize=1, NA.col = "red")
```

[image]